# Modifying Django Command argument

Tags: python, django, django-commands

Lets say i have a command like:

```
class Command(object):
    help = 'roll over and die'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '--foo',
            help='see command help',
            choices=['die','die_painfully'],
            required=True
        )
        parser.add_agument( ... )          x 9001
```

and now i want to have an almost identical class but i dont want the argument '--foo' to required anymore. Can u modify that parser somehow if i `super` the hole `add_arguments` in the inhering method or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class attribute:

```
class Command(object):
    help = 'roll over and die'
    foo_required = True

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '--foo',
            # ...
            required=self.foo_required
        )
```

and then in inheriting `Command`:

```
class Command(foo.bar.Command):
    foo_required = False
```

and you wouldn't have to override `add_arguments`.